# How do you multiply the values in the perimeter by the multiplier for this function?

Tags: python

This problem asks you to write two functions involving 
matrices/grids of integers, 
which are represented by two-dimensional lists.

(a)Write the functionmultiply_perimeter, which 
takes in a two-dimensional list of integers
(representing a grid of numbers and of any size) 
and multiplies the values that are on 
the perimeterof the grid by a given 
multiplier parameter,mutatingthe argument list. 
The perimeter of the grid is defined as the 
outer most rows and columns of the grid.

For instance, in the grid represented by
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]],
the function callmultiply_perimeter(L, 2) 
would operate on the bolded values in the grid below, mutating the grid by doubling the perimeter 
values to the result on the right.

```
1 2 3 4                    2 4 6 8
5 6 7 8                    10 6 7 16
9 10 11 12   would become  18 20 22 24
```

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
def multiply_perimeter(L: [[int]], multiplier: int) -> None:
    for x in L:
        x[0] = x * multiplier
        x[-1] = x * multiplier

        for y in x:
```

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

One possible way

- find the length of L, call it n.
- use a for loop with index i
- if i is 0 or n-1, change the element of L[i] by multiplying every element.
- suppose not only multiply the first and last element of L[i].

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve it using the code below:

```
def multiply_perimeter(L: [[int]], multiplier: int) -> None:
    size = len(L)
    if size > 0:
        # multiply only the first and last element in the lists L[1]...L[size-2]
        for _ in range(1, size-1):
            L[_][0] *= multiplier
            L[_][-1] *= multiplier
        # multiply first and last line elements by multiplier
        L[0] = [item*multiplier for item in L[-1]]
        L[-1] = [item*multiplier for item in L[-1]]
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the first row, `L[0] = [item*multiplier for item in L[0]]`?